# increment value in real time with mouse wheel in matlab

Tags: matlab, mousewheel, psychtoolbox

I want to be able to change the value of a number up an down based on the movement of the mouse wheel.  I have an image with a certain part having a different brightness and i want to adjust the brightness with the mouse wheel until i think they are the same.  I thought there was a function called windowscrollwheelfcn but that doesn't seem to exist on matlab 2017. I am also using the pyschtoolbox.

Unfortunately I am new to this and do not know where to begin.

```
[winID,winRect] = Screen('OpenWindow', 0, 128);
HideCursor;
im = round( 128*( 1 + argyle2 ) );
im(isnan(im)) = 150;
Screen('PutImage',winID,im,winRect);
Screen('Flip',winID);
```

Comment: [WindowScrollWheelFcn](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html?#property_d119e287293) is a `figure` window callback.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does `get(winID)` show?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Mac or Linux, you can use the Psychtoolbox function `GetMouseWheel` (it appears it isn't supported on Windows): http://docs.psychtoolbox.org/GetMouseWheel

If you're using Windows, you could use a key remapping program to map the mouse wheel up / down to other buttons, for example a keyboard button or a mouse button that is not otherwise present on the mouse (such as http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm ).